# Problem loading custom addon

Tags: python, scripting

first of all hi to everyone first post !
I've recently (10 days ago) started to learn Python specifically for Blender. Obviously I got eager to try something out and I cant (for obvious reason) find a solution to this problem.
I am an absolute beginner in programming and I don't have the right jargon so please be patient with me if I said something wrong  :).

What I want to achieve is having a custom panel for some extra settings under the Render Tab. I was able to do so and convert it to an Add-on (so I can have it loaded at startup) but my custom operator (that contains 2 actions) doesn't load up together with the Add-on.. I have to manually run the script but in this way I have to do it every time I log in.

I am super sure the problem is with my custom operator since in order to make this script I've basically just dug around other people/template scripts to see how they work.. without knowledge of what I am doing (I just go too excited)

all the help will be highly appreciated

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "HTML Render Combo",
    "author": "Virgil Sisoe",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "Properties > Render",
    "description": "Quick panel to export Documen HTML",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Render",
    }

import bpy
#DEFINE CUSTOM OPERATOR FOR HTML EXPORT
def main(context):
    # WANT IM TRYING IS TO HAVE A SINGLE BUTTON DOING RENDER AND EXPORT DOCUMEN
    bpy.ops.render.render()
    #DOCUMEN HTML IS AN ADDON I HAVE
    bpy.ops.scene.export_documen_html()

#CREATING CLASS
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Export HTML"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

# JUST COPIED AND PASTED FROM ANOTHER RENDER SOURCE IT IS COMPLETLY WRONG 
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        return scene 

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()

#DEFINE CUSTOM PANEL FOR EXPORT 
def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # ROW COLUMN LAYOUT
        row = layout.row()
        col = row.column(align = True)
        col.scale_y = 3
        row.operator("object.simple_operator", text="Render + HTML", icon='RENDER_STILL')
        #EXTERNAL ADDON (DOCUMEN)
        row.operator("scene.export_documen_html", text="HTML", icon='FILE')

        # LAYOUT EXPORT PATH 
        scene = context.scene
        box = layout.box()
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(scene, "documen_folderpath", text="Export Path")
        row.prop(scene, "buttons.directory_browse")

#render tab path      
def register():
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.append(draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.re.remove(draw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]
[image]

Ive added the .py file

[custom_export.py file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xWtuAayCoBnxE79UAMxAdrSHE3tJhKWO)

Comment: I can't get it to work with the way it is formatted right now, and I tried fixing indentions and still got confused about the last section. Can you fix it to look like what is working on your end?

Comment: if i copy and pasted it wont work for me either... I tried to follow the instruction for posting the code spacing it 4 times but I must have done something wrong. I've included the link for the .py file at the bottom of the post

Comment: Right off the bat, take a look at your register and unregister - you only need to combine them into one set of register and unregister at the bottom - the one that is in the middle is most likely stopping the script from reading further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `register` and `unregistered` functions. When running the script both are registered as the `__name__ == "__main__"` evaluates to `True` and use the version of those functions that are defined upon that time

When running as an add-on the full module is loaded and blender will handle the calls to `register` and `unregister` functions. After loading the module only the latest version of the `register` and `unregister` functions are known. Hence only the custom `draw` function is registered.

This can be fixed my merging the two `register` functions and the two `unregister` functions.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "HTML Render Combo",
    "author": "Virgil Sisoe",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "Properties > Render",
    "description": "Quick panel to export Documen HTML",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Render",
}

import bpy
#DEFINE CUSTOM OPERATOR FOR HTML EXPORT
def main(context):
    """for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)"""
    bpy.ops.render.render()
    bpy.ops.scene.export_documen_html()

#CREATING CLASS
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Export HTML"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
#CHECK
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

#DEFINE CUSTOM PANEL FOR EXPORT 
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    # write the layout code below here
    row = layout.row()
    col = row.column(align = True)
    col.scale_y = 3
    #row.operator("render.render", text="Render", icon='RENDER_STILL')
    row.operator("object.simple_operator", text="Render + HTML", icon='RENDER_STILL')
    row.operator("scene.export_documen_html", text="HTML", icon='FILE')

    scene = context.scene
    box = layout.box()
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scene, "documen_folderpath", text="Export Path")
    row.prop(scene, "buttons.directory_browse")

#render panel path      
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.append(draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.remove(draw)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

There are other stuff missing from the file like the `"scene.export_documen_html"` operator.

Comment: I'd suggest noting that when loaded as a module (ie the addon is enabled), blender calls   `custom_export.register()`  When run from the text editor (a case where `__name__ == "__main__"`) will use register method defined at time of call, explains why it seemingly works in text editor and not when enabled as an addon.

Comment: you absolutely right this has solve it and now it starts up properly when i log. funny enough I've tried to take away everything BUT that... . thank you very much